# How to handle image tag in Rich Text field in Sitecore, so that it can handle the media hash automatically?

Tags: caching, sitecore, media, rte

My Sitecore website is on 7.5. I have implemented a media protection request feature, but I can see too many errors in Sitecore logs saying that:

> ERROR MediaRequestProtection: An invalid/missing hash value was
>   encountered. The expected hash value:  Media URL: , Referring URL:

My question is How to handle an image tag in Rich Text field in Sitecore, so that it can handle the media hash automatically?

Comment: better to ask this question on - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Since version 7.5 Sitecore introduced a Media Request Protection which is a hash added to assets' URLs. I think that this was a good thing to avoid any kind of denial of service attacks.

On every incoming media request Sitecore calculates the hash of the request query string parameters and compares it with the given hash. If they are equal then Sitecore will perform the needed routine based on the provided URL parameters (for example, image resizing), but if they are not equal then Sitecore will throw a *MediaRequestProtection* error and send the original file as is.

There is a known issue in Sitecore Rich Text Editor (RTE) with **438674** *Ticket Id* and *"Media request protection is not applied to media in a hyperlink within the RTE" description*. Sitecore Support can provide a patch to override the method for rendering media links from RTE fields to also include the hash value. See the reference under Sitecore 8.2 release notes [here](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes).

If you don't have any Sitecore Support coverage by now then you can implement a workaround as follows:

1. Hook into `saveRichTextContent` pipeline to alter the RTE content before saving. For items that haven’t been modified after the `saveRichTextContent` pipeline has been introduced you can create a new `renderField` pipeline for Rich Text field type, but I would rather recommend to stick to `saveRichTextContent` pipeline approach and simply re-save all items with RTEs containing media assets.
2. Write your custom code to loop through images within the RTE HTML and modify the image rendering accordingly. Note, that you need to use `Sitecore.Resources.Media.HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl()` method to generate the full URL with the hash added, for example:

```
string mediaUrl = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(yourMediaItem);
string safeMediaUrl = Sitecore.Resources.Media.HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(mediaUrl);
```